# Set Custom Defined Type in DraftJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I'm curious if we can define our own block type instead of using one from [DRAFTBLOCKTYPE](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/src/model/constants/DraftBlockType.js).

Currently I'm playing with [draft-wysiwyg](https://github.com/bkniffler/draft-wysiwyg) which uses plugin named [draft-image-plugin](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/tree/master/draft-js-image-plugin). The problem is that I've to pass the `block-image` as the type of the block instead of `atomic` to make the plugin working.

Actually, I had tried to use the solution from [this](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/issues/373) where I override the plugin's type to `atomic`. But it affects other blocks with `atomic` type on the application where I can't create my own blockRendererFn since the blockRenderer is 'swallowed' by that plugin's blockRenderer.

To set the block type to `atomic`, I can easily achieved it by:

```
AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(
  editorState,
  entityKey,
  ' '
)
```

How to set the block type to any custom defined type such as `block-image` or `block-table`? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, and you have a few different options. Here are some I know of:

1. If you have control over the component that renders blocks of type `atomic`, it would probably be easiest to add your new type as an entity to those blocks.
2. If that's not an option, it get's a bit more cumbersome. `AtomicBlockUtils` is actually just a module made to help people create media (atomic) blocks easier (even though more utility functions will probably be added in the future). If you want the exact same behavior, but with a different type, you could copy [that module](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/72cc76fab1f00e7120efce2d5f7f98b6c5b2134c/src/model/modifier/AtomicBlockUtils.js) and just exchange `'atomic'` with something else (e.g. `'block-image'` or a variable to make it more generic/resuable).

   The technique they use is basically to create a selection of an empty block, and then use the [Modifier.setBlockType()](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/api-reference-modifier.html#setblocktype) function to give it a new block type:

```js
const asAtomicBlock = DraftModifier.setBlockType(
    afterSplit, // ContentState
    insertionTarget, // SelectionState
    'atomic' // your custom type
);
```

3. In [this example](https://github.com/brijeshb42/medium-draft), the author has created his own version, called `addNewBlock()` (it doesn't work exactly like the one in `AtomicBlockUtils` though):

```js
/*
Adds a new block (currently replaces an empty block) at the current cursor position
of the given `newType`.
*/
const addNewBlock = (editorState, newType = Block.UNSTYLED, initialData = {}) => {
  const selectionState = editorState.getSelection();
  if (!selectionState.isCollapsed()) {
    return editorState;
  }
  const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
  const key = selectionState.getStartKey();
  const blockMap = contentState.getBlockMap();
  const currentBlock = getCurrentBlock(editorState);
  if (!currentBlock) {
    return editorState;
  }
  if (currentBlock.getLength() === 0) {
    if (currentBlock.getType() === newType) {
      return editorState;
    }
    const newBlock = currentBlock.merge({
      type: newType,
      data: getDefaultBlockData(newType, initialData),
    });
    const newContentState = contentState.merge({
      blockMap: blockMap.set(key, newBlock),
      selectionAfter: selectionState,
    });
    return EditorState.push(editorState, newContentState, 'change-block-type');
  }
  return editorState;
};
```

So if you want to e.g. create a block of type 'block-image', with a src attribute, you can use this function like so:

```js
const newEditorState = addNewBlock(this.state.editorState, 'block-image', { src: 'https://...' })    
this.setState({ editorState: newEditorState })
```

**Update:**
If you add a new type, you also need to add it to your editor's blockRenderMap:

```
import { Map } from 'immutable'

<Editor 
  // editor props
  blockRenderMap={Map({
    ['unstyled']: {
      element: 'div'
    },
    ['block-image']: {
      element: 'div' // or whatever element you want as a wrapper
    },
    // all your other block types
  })}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Man. I tried to use the third option at the first place, but got no luck. I ended up using the second option. Now everything's running fine.

Comment: Fantastic answer!